# Available Video Recording formats for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5, format, video-capture

The functionality is to record a video from iPhone and upload it to server, then it should be synced with android device, and should be playable over there. From google search I came to know that iPhone records .mov files.

What I would like to know is, if there are any other formats available other than .mov so that it can be playable on android device as well as on the server.

Thanks.

```
SDK: 5.0;    
Xcode: 4.2;
Devices: iPhone 4,4S, iPad2,3
```

Answer (score 6):

.mov isn't a format; it's a container file.  The iPhone uses the popular h.264 encoder for video, and then contains it (with audio and data) in a .mov file, which is a quicktime file format. There is no way that you can change the container file or the encoder used by the iPhone.

There are services you can use to encoding video files from one format to another.  Check out zencoder and pandastream.

Comment: Thanks for the down-vote, 2.5 years after my response, which, I believe was accurate at the time.

Comment: This is a good answer and was correct at time of publication. It contains all the pertinent information from the time. Obviously the newer answer is better as it matches the updated functionality. But chuck w deserves the cred of a upvote.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way indeed. You can use the class **AVAssetExportSession**.
The AVAssetExportSession object has a property called *outputFileType* which you can set to **AVFileTypeMPEG4**.
By using the preset name *AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough* the video will not be actually re-encoded but just the container will be changed to mp4 (so it will be super fast).

```
AVAssetExportSession *exporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:#videoAsset# composition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
exporter.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
exporter.outputURL = outputURL;

[exporter exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
    switch (exporter.status) {
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            // Failed!
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            // Success!
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            // Cancelled!
            break;
    }
}];
```